# missing method body, or declare abstract

Tags: java

missing method body, or declare abstract error in java.!! any help?

```
public class PhraseOMatic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] wordListOne = {"come", "are", "let", "let's"};
        String[] wordListTwo = {"to", "you", "it", "hang"};
        String[] wordListThree = {"me", "there", "survive", "out"};

        int oneLength = wordListOne.length;
        int twoLength = wordListTwo.length;
        int threeLength = wordListThree.length;

        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
        int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
        int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * threeLength);

        String phrase = wordListOne[rand1] + " " + wordListTwo[rand2] + " " + wordListThree[rand3];
        System.out.println("What we need is a :" + phrase);
    }
}
```

missing method body, or declare abstract error in java.!! any help?

Comment: remove semicolon after the main method

Comment: yaa exactly..well..thank u soo much

Answer (score 3):

Yes, remove the `;` at the end of your `main` prototype line (first line). The compiler thinks that you want to declare it as `abstract`and you forgot the `abstract` keyword.

Comment: yaa exactly..well..thank u soo much